# ViewDidAppear not called for child view added to rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a child view controller over the top of all elements on screen (including navigation bars), and the only way I've found that works is to add it as a child view controller to my window's rootViewController:

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow,
        let view = window.rootViewController?.view
        else { return }
window.rootViewController?.addChildViewController(attachmentViewController)
view.addSubview(attachmentViewController.view)
attachmentViewController.view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.left.equalTo(view)
    make.right.equalTo(view)
    make.top.equalTo(view)
    make.bottom.equalTo(view)
}
attachmentViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: window.rootViewController)
```

However, this doesn't call the `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillDisappear` methods... Why is that? I really need it to.

Comment: Why are you using child view controller? You can add view controller over full screen with `push`

Comment: You should `present` the view controller and that will solve all of your problems, not `push` as was also suggested.

Comment: @slickdaddy thanks that worked, if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing all that, simply `present` the view controller (don't `push` it as suggested).

```
let destination = SomeViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard(self.storyboard!)
present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the "why is that?" of your question.

When you call `addChildViewController` to a view you're not changing the "stack" of view controllers at all or the state of the host view controller; you're just adding a view controller as a child controller of the main view.

Usually when you work with child view controllers you orchestrate calls like `willMove` and `didMove` to trigger the view controller lifecycle behaviour.

In your case, you may be better off with a push or present. Present will give you the capability of overlaying a view controller.

As a note, I have used an approach similar to what you describe for managing sign in/out states adding either a signed in child view controller or a signed out view controller. In which case, when they change I usually call methods like:

```
// To add the child
addChildViewController(child)
view.addSubview(child.view)
child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

// To remove the child.
child.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
child.removeFromParentViewController()
child.view.removeFromSuperview()
```